# Calculating average time per unit in Operations Dashboard for ArcGIS?

Tags: operations-dashboard

[image]

In the Operations Dashboard, I have a table with each item a number of units and a total time of how long worked.
Number of units and total time can make in visible.
But now I want to know how much time is consumed per unit.
example,
There are a total of 63 units and the total time is 56:30 hours.
So would the number calculated 0:53 hours and want to have visible in the Operations Dashboard.